# Dynamically populating an UnOrdered List

Tags: php, html

I am attempting following code to populate an UnOrdered List dynamically. The same type of code I am successfully using to populate a DropDown. But when I changed the tags to UnOrdered List, it is not working. When run, it just displays some tags instead of the actual output.

Where is the error:

```
<?php
    require("dbconnection.php");
    require("dbaccess.php");

    $divName = $_GET['DivName'];
    $ulName = $_GET['ControlName'];
    $query = $_GET['SqlQuery'];
echo $query;exit;
    dbconnection::OpenConnection();
    $result = dbaccess::GetRows($query);
?>
<ul id="<?php echo $ulName; ?>" name="<?php echo $ulName; ?>">
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
    <li><?php echo $row[1]; ?>"></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

The code that I used to populate a DropDown is below: It works absolutely fine:

```
<?php
    require("dbconnection.php");
    require("dbaccess.php");

    $dropdownControlName = $_GET['DropDownControlName'];
    $query = $_GET['SqlQuery'];
    dbconnection::OpenConnection();
    $result = dbaccess::GetRows($query);
?>
<select id="<?php echo $dropdownControlName; ?>" name="<?php echo $dropdownControlName; ?>">
<option>Select from the list</option>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></option>

<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: according to your code its looks fine. can u please send some more details related to your question

For example : give query detail or print the $row value for each iteration..

Comment: you have added this question in ajax but can u please show where and how you are using ajax?

Comment: Can you provide the result of your code? Your code have many 'disturbing' bad code, such as directly execute query from a `$_GET`, and looping the `$result` without checking if it have values or not. You should rewrite your code, checking all variable first before execute and looping it. You will get less bug by following best practice and write a tidy code, have a consistent indentation.

Comment: If you are passing raw sql query via url, its not merely bad code, its a (potential) disaster.

Comment: @Sejanus: Thanks for the note. I know that. First I need to make the code work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
<li><?php echo $row[1]; ?>"></li>
```

should be this:

```
<li><?php echo $row[1]; ?></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know Php but what this line doing :

```
echo $query;exit;
```

Comment: Sorry. I removed that line while using. I used it previously to know what is coming to $query.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have to use the second field of the result set?

```
    <li><?php echo $row[1]; ?>"></li>
```

There is an extra `>"` there.

Can you show us the resulting html code ?

SORRY: I was away from the PC for some minutes before posting, just saw that I answered the same as the following answer.

Answer (score 1):

HI,

I used your code and gave some constant values and i got the following out put.

Out Put:

- 1">
- 2">
- 3">
- 4">

  Used code:

    `
  - ">
    `

  and final Conclusion is, this prints the unordered list and i think yo may check your

  echo $row[1]; part for any html out puts.

  Note: "> This tag comes because of in your code having this value